# liverwire summernote not triggering changes in the textarea

Tags: javascript, laravel, summernote

could someone please assist, I am trying to use livewire components and summer note and I have the functionality working when its a normal input field, but as soon as I change the class to summer note, the values no longer update as I type. Any help would be much appreciated!
The livelier form:

```
<div>
    <p>{{ $note }}</p>
    <textarea class="summernote" id="kt_summernote_1" name="note" wire:model="note"></textarea>
</div>
```

The php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class LessonContentForm extends Component
{
    public $note;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.lesson-content-form');
    }
}
```

Finally the JS for SummerNote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
        // Class definition

        var KTSummernoteDemo = function () {
            // Private functions
            var demos = function () {
                $('.summernote').summernote({
                    height: 400,
                    tabsize: 2,
                });
            }

            return {
                // public functions
                init: function() {
                    demos();
                }
            };
        }();

        // Initialization
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            KTSummernoteDemo.init();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go will be to use a callback function.

```
    <div wire:ignore>
       <textarea wire:model.defer="description" id="summernote"></textarea>
    </div>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<script>
    $('#summernote').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Type something cool',
            tabsize: 2,
            height: 400,
            focus: true,
            toolbar: [
              ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
              ['para', ['paragraph']],
              ['insert', ['picture', 'video']],
            ],
            callbacks: {
                onChange: function(e) {
                      @this.set('description', e);
                },
            }
        });
</script>
```

This uses jQuery and also if your livewire property still isn't in sync with your editor then you need to dispatch a browser event from your livewire component for this editor script above.

Comment: Yes this good but `onChange` make the server sends many requests, which is very bad.